# How do I resolve shutter release button problems with a Nikon D5000?

Tags: nikon, repair, shutter-release

I have a Nikon D5000. I have had it for about 3 years or so. Of late I am having problems with the shutter release button (have to really push it down hard) before it takes a shot. Then on other occasions it works fine. When pressing it down the little "hour glass" appears then back to information screen and is repeated. If anyone has had similar problems, how did you resolve it? I am thinking of having it repaired, but I am trying to research the issue to see if there is anything I could do myself to fix it.

Comment: Assuming your firmware is up to date and you're not using a super slow SD card, I'd probably consider contact Nikon directly. Though some of your description does seem to imply that the camera has gotten busy transferring images to the card.

Comment: A few clarifications: does the shutter button  seem _physically_ hard to press? Is it really pressing harder that makes it work, or is it pressing for a longer time, or is it just trying repeatedly? Do you always get the hour glass when it's having this problem?

Comment: D3100 user here: I usually get significant, sometimes unbearable startup times when using an Eye-Fi. And in slightly cold weather coupled with low but still easy visibility lighting (think a public park just before sunset in mid-winter or a restaurant) AF successfully locks -- complete with green dot -- but the camera refuses to shoot even for whole seconds no matter how hard I hold down or mash the shutter release.

Answer (score 2):

Considering it has already reach a 3-years, check if it has already reached its actuation count limit.  Every DSLR has its actuation limit of more or less 100,000.  Meaning if you have already taken 100k shots, you have reached the life span of its shutter.  But nothing to worry, just bring it to the Nikon service center, then they will replace it and it will be good as new, and the shutter count will be reset.

To check if you reach the limit, upload a picture of your latest shot to http://www.myshuttercount.com/

Comment: Thank you so much, i will do that. Thanks again regards Alan

Comment: I tried as you suggested and its only on 29 000 , so i think a visit to a Nikon Service Cenre will be the best solution ?

Comment: ow, well it will be better to bring it the Nikon Service Center.  Maybe there's another problem.

Comment: I thought it lasts forever if you take care of it, is this info true?